# How can I see the site and edit in the graphical way in Sharepoint Designer 2013?

Tags: 2013

I try to open the site of Sharepoint 2013 via Sharepoint Designer, but I see only coded page. I remember in 2010 version i could graphically esit the page. Any suggestions how can I do this in 2013?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Design view was there until 2010 but was removed in 2013.

You would have to edit the Code View to manipulate the XSLT and XML manually to produce the result you wanted.

[image]

Reference [link](http://blog.sharepoint-videos.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-data-view-web-part-list-view-web-part-design-view-is-gone/)

Answer (score 1):

In `SharePoint Designer 2010` we used to find 3 types of views for editing pages and master pages.

1. Code View
2. Design View
3. Split View

But now with the release of `SharePoint Designer 2013` Microsoft has remove the `Design View` and `Split View`, and they announced it on their blogs.

`Keenan Newton`, who is a senior product marketing manager on the SharePoint team has mentioned below in this [Office blog](https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/10/changes-to-the-design-view-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

> With SharePoint Server 2013 embracing new web standards for client
>   side rendering of pages such as JavaScript, JSON, and OData, there is
>   no longer a need to support a visual web page editor within SharePoint
>   Designer. With that in mind, we removed the ability to visually edit
>   pages in SharePoint Designer 2013 because its page editor is designed
>   to only understand the unique features of a SharePoint web page. With
>   our support of new web standards, any web page designer can now be
>   used for editing web pages in SharePoint Server 2013. This includes
>   form customization, conditional formatting of page content, layout,
>   theming and branding. To simplify the process of integrating
>   customized SharePoint pages, SharePoint Server 2013 includes a new
>   feature called the **SharePoint Design Manager**. This feature enables a
>   web designer to export a web page from SharePoint, customize it, and
>   then import it back into SharePoint, all right from the SharePoint
>   site.
>
> SharePoint Designer 2013 will continue to support site, workflow,
>   list, library, and external data customization and configuration.
>   However, we will look for opportunities to leverage SharePoint itself
>   as the primary tool for customization and configuration tasks.

Also there are good reading content on [What's changed in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj728659.aspx) where they give reason for this change as below.

> Compared to current versions of Internet Explorer, Design view is an
>   older technology that does not support many new HTML5 and CSS tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. They removed this in 2013.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE, why does this not provide an answer? The truth is that this part was removed in SP D 2013

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. The Design view (and related Split view) have been removed in SharePoint Designer 2013.

According to Microsoft, this is because the Design view simply could not work with modern standards such as HTML5 and related features in SharePoint 2013.